# Yii (Query Builder) How to loop to get all column values

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am trying to count how many times a `Department` ask a `Concern`.

**EDIT:** Currently, when I cVardump, the query outputs the **WRONG** result. But I run the query in phpmyadmin, it outputs the right result.

When I implement together with the loop, it doesn't work. It only outputs a single `Concern`, where the database contains 2 `Concern`.

I don't know, but I think it's in my foreach loop. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$query = $datacon->createCommand()

    ->select('COUNT(a.dept_id) as countDept,dept_name, concern')
    ->from('transaction a')
    ->join('department b' , 'a.dept_id = b.dept_id')
    ->group('dept_name', 'concern')
   // ->limit(10)
    ->queryAll();

    ob_end_clean();

/*CVarDumper::dump($query,15,true);
exit;*/



$html2 = '<h2 align="center"><small>FAQ (Sorted per Issue)</small></h2>

        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">

        <tr>
            <th align="center">Issue</th>
            <th align="center">Department</th>
            <th align="center">No. of times asked</th>
        </tr>';

        $count = 0;

     foreach ($query as $row)
        {
            $issue = $row['concern'];
            $dept_name = $row['dept_name'];
            $countDept = $row['countDept'];



    $html2 .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$issue.'</td>
            <td>'.$dept_name.'</td>
            <td align="center">'.$countDept.'</td>

        </tr>';
        }

    $html2 .= '</table> ';

    $pdf->writeHTML($html2, true, false, true, false, '');
```

**EDIT:** Result of VarDump

```
array
(
    0 => array
    (
        'countDept' => '2'
        'dept_name' => 'Dialysis'
        'concern' => 'DSFSDFSDFSAFSAF'
    )
    1 => array
    (
        'countDept' => '4'
        'dept_name' => 'Nurse Ward'
        'concern' => 'DSFSDFSDFSAFSAF'
    )
)
```

Comment: Share the vardump results?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to group by `dept_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach ($query as $row)
{
        foreach ($row as $r)
        {
            $issue = $r['concern'];
            $dept_name = $r['dept_name'];
            $countDept = $r['countDept'];
            $html2 .= '
            <tr><td>'.$issue.'</td>
            <td>'.$dept_name.'</td>
            <td align="center">'.$countDept.'</td></tr>';
        }
}
```

**OR**

```
foreach ($query as $row)
{
        foreach ($row as $r)
        {
            $html2 .= '<tr><td>'.$r['concern'].'</td>
            <td>'.$r['dept_name'].'</td>
            <td align="center">'.$r['countDept'].'</td></tr>';
        }
}
```

**OR**

```
 foreach ($query as $row)
    {
            for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++)
            {
                $d=$row[$i];
                $html2 .= '<tr><td>'.$d['concern'].'</td>
                <td>'.$d['dept_name'].'</td>
                <td align="center">'.$d['countDept'].'</td></tr>';
            }
    }
```

Comment: I tried both but it outputs error saying "Illegal string offset".

Comment: Try the third option and if fails share me the output of $d, echo vardump($d);

Comment: It's an error saying : "Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i". And when I vardump it returns no array, it outputs the same error.

Comment: Sorry my mistake it must be $i. I have changed the third option. Check it